# Change CPU capacity of Docker containers

Tags: docker

I'm doing an internship focused on Docker and I have to load-balance an application which have a client, a server and a database. My goal is to dynamically scale the number of server containers according their CPU usage. For instance if the CPU usage is over 60% I add a new container on the fly to divide the CPU usage. My problem is that my simulation does not get the CPU usage higher than 20%, it is a very simple simulation where a random users register and go to random pages.

**Question :** How can I lower the CPU capacity of my server containers using my docker-compose file in order to artificially make the CPU go higher ? I tried to use the cpu_quota and cpu_shares instructions but it's not very documented and I don't know how it works or affects my containers.

Comment: Another option is to increase cpu load on the containers using stress utilities. Try http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/